# Handling ports in Shipyard Load Balancer with Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I'd like to have Shipyard running in my server and I'm trying to run it with shipyard/deploy container. It runs multiple containers and one of them is a load balancer that runs at port 80.

Problem is that I'm handling my containers with Nginx installed on the host, out of containers, at port 80 too. Of course both cannot be together so I need to customize Shipyard load balancer run to be mapped to a different port in my host. I don't see an easy way to do this, how can be this situation handled? The way containers are linked is dependent of the mapping with host ports?

I'm wondering too if the way I'm handling my containers is the proper one..For example, I'm planning to add a Redmine instance. By default the trusted build is running on port 80 but I guess I can just map to other port and configure nginx to point there when accessing redmine.domain.com. There is a better way to handle this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right; you need to change the port (or the IP address, if your machine has multiple IP addresses), either for your Nginx load balancer, or for Shipyard's.

You can customize Shipyard by altering the [run.sh](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard-deploy/blob/33049555ef41ef7ba95da8aec0652e32bab640fe/run.sh#L52) file and rebuilding its container.